# About adding Stanford NLP (NER) JAR (from JAVA) in my Android project

Tags: java, android, jar

I am doing research related with Natural Language Processing, NLP. 
For this Stanford NER JAR (from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Download) is needed to be added in my Android project.

I'm working on Android 4.2 Ver. with Eclipse. 
What I did is as follows:
1) I added JAR to /libs  with error, [2014-12-02 03:08:52 - CS548_Client] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
2) I used add External JAR from JAVA Build Path
3) 1) + 2)

But nothing works.

How can I use this JAR file in my Android project?